# Batch Dir Doubling

Tags: batch-file, dir

When I run the following line:

```
dir C:\FILENAME *.bat /b > C:\TEXTFILE.txt
```

I receive the following in the TEXTFILE.txt:

```
BATCHNAME.bat
BATCHNAME.bat
```

How can I make it output just the name of each file once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
dir C:\FILENAME\*.bat /b > C:\TEXTFILE.txt
               ^
     note the added backslash
```

Assuming you're *in* the `c:\filename` directory, your original command will get two copies because it's *asking* for two separate things.

Comment: This fixed the problem, I must have accidentally deleted the backslash. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
dir C:\FILENAME\*.bat /b > C:\TEXTFILE.txt
```

You are asking `dir` command to list two different sets of files, the content of C:\FILENAME and (there is a space between) the list of all .BAT files in current directory. So, two lines into the output file